# Is it possible to get N number of records per a value in a joined table WITHOUT multiple queries?

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework, greatest-n-per-group, django-orm

So I have three tables:

`article_page` - (for my articles) represented by the model Page

`article_page_category` - glue table between article_page and article_category as they're many to many

`article_category` - category information, represented by the model Category

I want to make a query to the database that gets N number of records (10 to 20 probably) PER category, preferably in one query, as I can have a lot of categories at once, and this can be quite expensive.

I've been trying all sorts of different types of queries and I'm having no luck - I've even tried various subqueries but that didn't translate amazingly well to Django, and raw sql queries were difficult to get working.

To give an example:

So let's say I have the categories of business, technology, sports

I want to get 10 articles from business, 10 from technology, and 10 from sports - all of which are categories in article_category

Is there a way to do that with one query?

I've got something like this right now, but I really think this isn't the right approach:

```
class GroupedArticleListView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        categories = Category.objects.filter(taxon=1)
        categories = categories.annotate(
        top_articles=Subquery(
            Page.objects.filter(
                category=OuterRef("pk")
            ).order_by("-date").values_list("id", flat=True)[:10].first(),
            output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        )
```

The database is MySQL, if that is important for the answer

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how to translate this into the Django ORM, but the best way to accomplish this is with window functions (requires MySQL 8.0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT ...,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ac.category_id ORDER BY a.date DESC) AS rownum
  FROM article_page AS a
  JOIN article_page_category AS ac ON a.id = ac.article_id
) AS t
WHERE rownum <= 10;
```

I've read that Django 2.0 has support for window functions, but I'm not a Django user so I'll leave it to you to research that. See for example https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2017/12/django-20-window-expressions-tutorial/

Comment: Hrm yep, this pretty perfectly gives me the result I want and the query is super performant. I will either figure out a way to do this directly and pipe the data out without worrying about Django, or convert it over to a Django query. Thank you so much!